# How can I do WHERE, ORDER BY, and LIMIT range at the same time with a MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql

can do LIMIT range by itself.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* 
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_1.id = table_2.ID 
LIMIT 17402,17423
```

can do WHERE and ORDER BY at same time.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* 
FROM table_1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 
ON table_1.id = table_2.ID 
WHERE AVAILABLE > 4 
ORDER BY table_1.id ASC
```

can't do WHERE, ORDER BY and LIMIT range at same time.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* 
FROM table_1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 
ON table_1.id = table_2.ID 
WHERE AVAILABLE > 4 
ORDER BY table_1.id ASC 
LIMIT 17402,17423
```

can't do WHERE and LIMIT range at same time with ORDER BY removed.

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* 
FROM table_1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 
ON table_1.id = table_2.ID 
WHERE AVAILABLE > 4 
LIMIT 17402,17423
```

would like to do WHERE and LIMIT range at same time, or all 3 if possible.

Comment: What do you mean "can't do"?  THe queries look correct syntactically.

Comment: results are zero when i do the 3rd and 4th versions.  just blank whiteness.

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact use limit with where and order by. Maybe you are having issues because once you include the where clause, you don't have 17402 rows?

Comment: Beat me to it, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

@BradleyKaiser beat me to it, you are limiting your result set with the `WHERE` clause and therefore no longer having the same `LIMIT` rows you had before.

If you know for a fact you want those specific rows, then filtered down by your `WHERE` clause, you could always do a subquery:

```
SELECT Id
    ,Available
FROM (
    SELECT table_1.id AS Id
        ,table_2.AVAILABLE AS Available
    FROM table_1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.ID 
    LIMIT 17402,17423
) AS Subset
WHERE Available > 4 
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

You will need to take the time to list your columns as I did here (which you should do anyway, for maintenance reasons), but with this subquery setup it will first retrieve records based on your `LIMIT`, then filter and order the resulting record set.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\app\index.php on line 78
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0020 148200 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 2.9992 155792 mysql_fetch_array ( ) ..\index.php:78

Comment: (A) you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` because it is outdated and horribly insecure compared to the `mysqli_*` syntax, and (B) you asked a MySQL question with only a MySQL tag, and got a MySQL answer. If you want a more "complete" answer, then provide more complete information in the question.